# How to add quick edit on the list of users to edit custom fields?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

Hope everyone is doing well,
I need to add quick edit action or bulk edit option on the list of users so that I can edit custom fields of an user.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? And where are you trying to put the edit link?

Comment: I am trying to put bulk edit for users list in wordpress.

Comment: I gathered "in WordPress" from the site we are on. I meant where in WordPress - front end, admin user list, admin area menu, etc.. More importantly, what steps have you taken and at what point did you get stuck?